# I'm trying to find/ display all the numbers in a table that start with any 2 digits from another table using laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, matching

I've been searching all over the internet and I just can't find anything that relates to my needs. I'm having trouble even figuring out how to go about this problem.  I have a view that list all the 2 digits numbers from a table called fsgdata in mysql.  Each 2 digit number is a clickable link.  Now what I want to do is when I click on one of these 2 digits numbers, it will go to another view, that displays all these 4 digit numbers from another table (called fscdata) that starts with the 2 digit I clicked on.  The closest answers I have even found to this problem is either an array or letterbased, right now struggling to bring this idea to life in laravel 5/ php.

These are the 2 methods in the controller:

```
public function FSCG_List()
{
    $fsg_list_all = fsgdata::all();

    return View('FSC_views.FSCG_List', compact('fsg_list_all'));
}
public function FSC_List($id)
{

    $fsg_find_id = fsgdata::find($id);
    $fsc_list_all = fscdata::all();

    return View('FSC_views.FSC_List', compact('fsg_find_id','fsc_list_all'));
}
```

first view showing the FSG numbers:

```
 @extends('layout.master')
 @section('content')
<div class="figure"><img src="/Content/images/figure2.jpg" /></div>
<div class="main">
    <h2>FSG List</h2>
    <ul>
        @foreach($fsg_list_all as $fsg_find_id)
            <a href='/FSC_List{{ $fsg_find_id->id }}'>{{$fsg_find_id->fsg_number}}</a></br>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endsection
```

Second view showing the related FSC Numbers:

```
@extends('layout.master')
@section('content')
<div class="figure"><img src="/Content/images/figure2.jpg" /></div>
<div class="main">
    <h2>Search Results for FSG Number: {{ $fsg_find_id->fsg_number }}</h2>
    <ul>
        @foreach($fsc_list_all as $fsc_find_id)
                <a href='/NSN_list{{ $fsc_find_id->id }}'>{{$fsc_find_id->fsc_number}}</a></br>
        @endforeach

    </ul>
 </div>
@endsection
```

Of course as of right now thit is showing the entire FSC table as oppose to the matching.  Now I would like to go the route of nesting an `if` statement within the `foreach`.  Is there some type of index type command like in python? Sorry, I usually like to to have more work written down to attack the problem, but I'm not sure how to approach and it.  Thanks in advance to anyone who can help

Comment: Of course, what you ask for is possible... but it's a strange requirement.  If you consider there to be a relationship between records in your database, you really ought to define the schema in such a way that the RDBMS (*relational database management system*, i.e. MySQL) has knowledge of them so that it can do its job properly and *manage* those *relationships* for you!  Your current schema does not do this (and, as a byproduct of the poor design, solving this particular problem is marginally more difficult than it would otherwise be).

Comment: that still doesn't really answer my question, that's more along the lines of alternative method that you find to be more efficient and effective to an issue that i wasn't seeking guidance for.  That falls under a suggestion and while appreciate the advice, I'm really looking for answer to my question.

Comment: Indeed.  Which is why I posted that as a comment and not as an answer.  For my own part, I'm not interested in helping people to build bad software, so I shan't be posting an answer to this question.  Good luck!

Comment: this is what was asked of me to do.  In life you're suppose to do what your asked to do, expectations is a part of life and coding .  This what was expected of me from another person, so this is what I'm going to do, and i would appreciate understanding rather than snarky remarks.  If it's possible, then why not do it?  Working on code gets you better at coding regardless if it's bad practice or not.  Hence the word progression.  Eventually i will discover a better practice, but i won't get get better by being completely stumped.  Which is why when you first start coding, they say it's get to

Comment: good to make mistakes, because you learn from them, but sure don't help me.  If you truly think it will somehow make me worse....

Comment: I don't find The Nuremberg Defense particularly persuasive: if I'm instructed to do something badly, I see it as my responsibility to educate my superiors as to why their instructions are harmful and how we would all benefit from a better approach.  But I'm not trying to stop you from obtaining an answer to your question—I've neither voted to close it, nor have I downvoted.  I'm just saying that **I** would prefer to spend the (really rather limited) time that I have available for helping people on this site on issues that assist them in becoming better programmers.

Comment: Fair enough, that is your opinion and your entitled to it, good day sir